# I want to set the n-th bit to the right from a pointer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Lets say we get memory like so:

```
void* start = calloc(1,1); // 1 byte = 8bits all 0 -> 00000000 and i want to get 00100000
```

How do I set the 3rd bit for example after the pointer to 1?

If the block is big for example:

```
void* start = calloc(1, 1024); // and you want n-th bit n > 8

((unsigned char*)start)[n/CHAR_BIT] |= (1 << (n % CHAR_BIT));
```

Comment: `calloc(0,1)` allocates zero bytes. It returns a valid pointer, but the memory it points to cannot be legally accessed. Assuming that's fixed, you are probably looking for something like `((char*)start)[0] |= (1 << 3);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know calloc  reserves the memory is that what you mean when you say "allocates zero bytes" or is it because I ask for 1 byte?

Comment: Why do you think you `"...ask for 1 byte"`?  [`calloc(0, 1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3p.html) requests memory for 0 items each with the same size as a `char`.

Comment: @G.M. my bad I thought the first parameter did something else

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from the comments on your code, you want:

```
void* start = calloc(1,1); // Allocate memory for 1 element with 1 byte size
*((char*)start) |= (1 << 5); // Set the 6th bit from right (00100000)
```

Comment: Better to just assign the result of `calloc()` to an `unsigned char *` (or `char *`) in the first place, and then not have to deal with casts.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I just tried to keep the var type from the original code.

Comment: What if the pointer points to something bigger like calloc(1,1024), how would you set a bit > 8?

Comment: It depends on the value that you need to represent, you must make the cast to the variable size that better suits your need. You can allocate 1024 bytes of memory with `calloc(1,1024)` and use that as an array of 1024 `uint8` or an array of 512 `uint16`, and so on. If you need to do the bit shifting on all the 1024 bytes, you must consider the use of a loop (for, while).